# WebCore bmalloc::IsoAllocator crashes in iOS 11.3

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview, webkit, ios11.3

I am getting crash like this in fabric crashlytics:

## WebCore

bmalloc::IsoAllocator >::allocateSlow(bool)

Any clue to resolve this issue?

Comment: Same issue here? Are you using a UIWebView or WKWebView?

Comment: In my case, I was using UIWebView. I changed it to WKWebView and the crash never happens again.

Answer (score 1):

i'm getting same crash.

in my case, when large html load on webview and inline css in the html was reason.

check your html content.

---

this is knowledge in my case. not a question.

more detail is

i'm using UIWebView.

my same crash was to occur when client updated on ios 11.3

i checked all webview.

when call loadrequest on uiwebview function.

crash occured when large html load. the html content size was

char length 80000 ~ 200000. it's breaking on css in html content.

this is my case. I hope it helps.

Comment: I got the same error and the answer is the root cause of my issue. I've appended too much data to the webview and got this error. Reducing the amount of data resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to set the webView.delegate to nil after I used the webView.